# Elixir function clauses: list of strings vs list of numbers vs tuple of strings vs tuple of numbers

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I want to specify 4 clauses for an Elixir function with the following patterns:
i) list of strings 
ii) list of numbers
iii) tuple of strings
iv) tuple of numbers

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this probably:

```
def foo([]),                      do: :empty
def foo([h|t]) when is_binary(h), do: :list_of_strings
def foo([h|t]) when is_number(h), do: :list_of_numbers
def foo(tuple) when is_tuple(tuple) do
  # Convert tuple to list of stuff, then recursively call foo
  tuple |> tuple_to_list |> foo
end
```

The last clause assumes you don't care about getting a tuple back from `foo`.

Comment: good call on converting tuple to list and just using the list functions.

Comment: I should also note that this by no means guarantees that the whole list/tuple will be either strings or numbers, you'd have to use one of the functions in `Enum` to check the entire list/tuple if you need that guarantee.

Comment: right, it'll call is_binary for the strings, is_number for the numbers and is_default if neither.